# jQuery - Changing value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this field in **one form**:

```
<input type="text" name="promocode" id="promoCode" value="" style="width:24%" maxlength="5">
```

and this field in another form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" class="promo" value="" />
```

How can I do, so whenever the value of `#promoCode` is changed, it will also change the value of `.promo`

Currenlty, I have this:

```
var promo = $("#promoCode").val();
$("#promoCode").change(function(){
    $('.promo').val(promo);    
});
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: is your code wrapped in a dom ready callback?

Comment: Probably `#echo` should be `.promo` or `input[name="custom"]`.

Comment: @Engineer. Where did you see `#echo`?

Comment: @gdoron It was `$('#echo').val(promo); ` before editting .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#promoCode").change(function(){
        $('.promo').val(this.value);    
    });
});
```

- Make sure the DOM is ready when you attach your callback to the change event
- `this` inside callback is the element the event attached to.
- If you cache `#promoCode` value outside the change callback it will be out of sync right after the first change! use `this.value` inside the callback just like I did.